# Cakephp Routing to generate URL parameter

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

Simple question for Cakephp 2.0.

I want to set a routing rule such that:

```
www.abc.com/z/abc123
```

will resolve to the full URL of (including the URL parameter)

```
www.abc.com/bookings/bookingref/?ref=abc123
```

Where bookings is the Controller, and bookingref is the action.

Can someone teach me what I need to write in the routes.php?

Kevin

Answer (score 0):

In routes.php:

```
Router::connect('/bookingref/', array('controller' => 'bookings', 'action' => 'bookingref'));
```

In controller:

```
public function bookingref(){


}
```

So you should have a view name after your function. i.e. `bookingref.ctp`

Comment: I don't think this is the answer, I want to convert "www.abc.com/z/abc123" to "www.abc.com/bookings/bookingref/?ref=abc123"

Comment: You need to rephrase your question

Comment: But also you can do a redirect. If I go to `www.abc.com/z/abc123` in your controller function `return $this->redirect('/bookings/bookingref/?ref=abc123')`

Comment: Thanks for that, but I want to do it in the routes.php file. I don't want to create a controller just for this..., any solution?

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would implement your solution:

In Config/routes.php add:

```
Router::connect('/z/:reference',
    ['controller' => 'bookings', 'action' => 'bookingref'],
    [
        'pass' => ['reference'],// Passed to corresponding function argument (order matters if 2 or more)
        'reference' => '[a-z0-9]+'// RegExp validation if you need it
    ]
 );
```

In your BookingsController use:

```
public function bookingref($reference = null)
{
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, `Router::redirect()` cannot redirect to string based URLs that include variables. The controller based approach Progredi mentioned is your best bet.